# R error: If argument has zero length (Double For Cycle)

Tags: r, for-loop, if-statement

I'm trying to write a binary function that returns 1 or 0 if the next period return is positive or negative. To do so, I tried with this code:

```
signal<- matrix(0, nrow = nrow(returns), ncol = ncol(returns))
for (i in 1:(ncol(returns))){
  for (t in 2:(nrow(returns)+1)){ 
    signal[1,i]<- 0 #Inizialize the signal binary function giving 0 to the first row
    if (returns[t,i] > returns[t-1,i]){ 
    signal[t,i] <- 1
    }else{
    signal[t,i]<- 0}
  }
}
```

but this gives me the error "if argument has zero length".
I need this function to give a response (0,1) for all the times of each asset(columns)

Comment: [`site:stackoverflow.com "if argument has zero length"`](https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+"if+argument+has+zero+length").

Comment: Your `t` iterates one past the number of rows, so `returns[t,i]` should fail.